# Intermittent Video Issues with Radeon HD 7750

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, radeon, gpu-driver

I am completely new to Ubuntu and Linux, so please forgive me if I am asking a stupid question (or two).

I am using an old LG TV (32lf11) as my monitor, connected via HDMI plugged into my video card (Radeon HD 7750). That video card isn't listed [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsAti), but it [looks like](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) the Radeon HD 7750 is supported by Ubuntu 16.04 by default.

When I look under "additional drivers" I don't see anything for the video card.

I don't know if it's related, but my display is automatically detected as a Goldstar 52", which is obviously not accurate. But it looks ok, so after a little poking around, I just left it alone.

Here's some more info:

```
~$ lshw -c video WARNING: you should run this
 program as super-user.   *-display               
        description: VGA compatible controller
        product: Cape Verde PRO [Radeon HD 7750/8740 / R7 250E]
        vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
        version: 00
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
        configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
        resources: irq:46 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:f4e00000-f4e3ffff ioport:e000(size=256)
 memory:f4e40000-f4e5ffff WARNING: output may be incomplete or
 inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

The problem I'm running into is that my monitor flickers intermittently, and occasionally the entire system crashes and I get a pink screen (not sure if that's the Ubuntu default desktop just getting stuck or what). This is exacerbated by playing videos (be it VLC, Youtube, or Plex), but it will eventually freeze regardless.

I don't know what steps I should take at this point. Should I try a different driver? I'm confused about how to go about that. Or maybe I should opt for different hardware? Or even another version of Ubuntu? I'm open to whatever suggestion you think might be easiest and best for someone who is just starting out.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why is "Goldstar 52" inaccurate? LG originally stood for Lucky Goldstar. As for drivers, you may want to install 14.04. 16.04 doesn't support the proprietary AMD drivers, and that may be the source of your issues. Flickering and crashing sound a lot like a broken graphics card, but it happening during graphical tasks also points to the lack of an adeqtuate driver. Downgrade to 14.04, since that's easier (and cheaper) than getting a new GPU. If that doesn't work, then buy an NVIDIA-based card.

Comment: Because it thinks it's a 52" screen and it's a 32" screen. Edit: Thanks for the advice. I will give 14.04 a try. Do you know if that will include the drivers or if they'll show up in the "additional drivers"?

Comment: That 52 might not mean the measurement, but it also could. Either way, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I stand corrected, then. It actually has the " after it, so I assumed that referred to the inches.

Comment: Well, like I said, maybe it does refer to the supposed screen size, but that's an issue we don't need to worry about :p.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Intel/Radeon 7400m and whenever I plug my TV using HMDI I get the same flickering, it gets worse when using Chrome. My 46" LG TV is also listed as Goldestar 52" and I'm using default Ubuntu 16.04 driver.

My workaround was to lower the refresh rate to 50hz using `xrandr -r 50` even thou my TV supports 1080p at 120Hz

Comment: Thanks! I did try a few different refresh rates after fresh installing 14.04 and I still seem to have the same troubles. I will be sure to check whether I have it set at 50hz next time. It's worth a try.